# How can I auto extend text filed with autocomplete in Interactive grid?

Tags: oracle-apex

I created list of values for text filed with autocomplete item in Interactive grid .

The text can be 1000 character , I created list of values because I dont need to type every time the

complete paragraph , now the issue how can I auto extend the item size to be multiline and show the complete written paragraph ?

```
I changed the width in appearance to 1000 character but still not show the complete paragraph
```

How to do that or can I use another item and connect it with list of values like popup LOV but I need after select the data from list of values to add more text and write more data not only select from list of values ?